# Hyperledger Fabric and Hyperldger composer API

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

After starting Hyperledger composer rest server, I could get all the REST API’s pertaining to my Business network definition. However, I would also like to query world state and other Fabric related features.

In this case, Should I use combination of both Fabric Rest Composer API + Fabric SDK APIs ?

Answer (score 0):

The Composer REST Server is simply showing you the world state, just abstracting away the details of access so as a developer you only have to worry about CRUD operations.

If you're just doing CRUD, Composer should have you fully covered as their default implementation is CouchDB.

Not sure what other features you would want to use to require Fabric SDK. Composer has [great documentation](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/introduction/introduction.html) on using most Fabric features without going against the grain of Composer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to ChrisMcQueen answer ...

You can also write Queries in Composer to access the data via the REST server.

Composer has the concepts of Registries for Assets, Participants and Transactions - if you don't use Composer you will have to define, generate and manage these things yourself.  You can't access these registries through the Fabric SDK.

Comment: Just wanted to ask another question @R Thatcher, is there a way to customize the APIs that are available through composer-rest-server?

Comment: Have a look in this folder: `/home/<USERNAME>/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/server/`